# Substring depois de caracter C#

Tags: c#, substring

Boa Tarde

```
string nr = ABC:1
```

Gostaria de pegar o numero após ":", como faria?

```
nr = nr.substring(...);
```

Resultado esperado:

para `nr = ABC:50`

```
nr = 50;
```

para `nr = LKfasEWF:5039`

```
nr = 5039
```

Comment: Explique melhor, você tem uma *string* qualquer com algum texto, dentro deste texto pode/deve ter um `:` e você quer tudo o que tem depois dele? Pode não ter o `:`? Pode ter mais que um? O que fazer nestes casos? Se tiver espaço o que deve fazer com ele? Inclui ou não? Para programar primeiro precisa entender o problema, e especificar cada detalhe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para isso, basta pegar a posição que o caractere/string está, e depois usar a substring começando dessa posição+1. Segue exemplo.

```
string nr = "ABC: 1";

int posicaoCaractere = nr.IndexOf(": ");

nr = nr.Substring(posicaoCaractere+1);

MessageBox.Show(nr);
```